# More elegant way to compare char+1 against char in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

For my code below, seeking input on a more concise way to compare the char and char + 1 in a string without running into an "index out of range" error.

i have run into two coding competition problems that require me to take a string, and keep track of a tally based on if a value repeats itself twice within the string. as of now, my solution is to create a string w/o the first char, compare the two strings in a for loop at the length of the shorter string, and then compare the last two characters outside of the for loop.

```
n = int(input())
unique = ""

for i in range(n):
    p = input()
    unique += p

ahead = unique[1::]
sum = 1

for i in range(len(ahead)):
    if unique[i] == ahead[i]:
        sum += 0
    else:
        sum += 1

if unique[-1] == unique[-2]:
    sum += 1
else:
    sum += 1

print(sum)
```

Comment: It'll be easier to help if you share an example input and the expected output.

Comment: In your example script, instead of getting data from `input`, set a value for `unique` and include the expected result for that one string. That makes it easier for us to test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a much simpler approach to the problem it seems like you're trying to solve:

```py
In [1]: s = "hello abbey, nonplussed to see you"

In [2]: sum(s.count(char*2) for char in set(s))
Out[2]: 4
```

It works by iterating over the unique characters of a string (found by simply casting to `set`), and counting the number of occurrences of that character doubled. E.g., on the first iteration with that example string, `char` is `'h'` and so we compute how many times `'hh'` occurs in the string (zero times).

If you insist on comparing pairs of characters, use `zip()`:

```py
In [3]: s = "hello"
   ...: for t in zip(s, s[1:]):
   ...:     print(t)
   ...:
('h', 'e')
('e', 'l')
('l', 'l')
('l', 'o')
```